# inputstream null pointer exception when using modified last.fm's Caller.java

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

For some reason I'm getting null pointer exception. It's downloading the image here and logcat points me to call

```
public Result call(final String method, final String apiKey, final String... params) {
    return call(method, apiKey, map(params));
}

/**
 * Performs the web-service call. If the <code>session</code> parameter is
 * <code>non-null</code> then an authenticated call is made. If it's
 * <code>null</code> then an unauthenticated call is made.<br/>
 * The <code>apiKey</code> parameter is always required, even when a valid
 * session is passed to this method.
 * 
 * @param method The method to call
 * @param apiKey A Last.fm API key
 * @param params Parameters
 * @param session A Session instance or <code>null</code>
 * @return the result of the operation
 */
public Result call(final String method, final String apiKey, Map<String, String> params) {
    params = new WeakHashMap<String, String>(params);
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    // no entry in cache, load from web
    if (inputStream == null) {
        // fill parameter map with apiKey and session info
        params.put(PARAM_API_KEY, apiKey);
        try {
            final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = openPostConnection(method, params);
            inputStream = getInputStreamFromConnection(urlConnection);

            if (inputStream == null) {
                lastResult = Result.createHttpErrorResult(urlConnection.getResponseCode(),
                        urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                return lastResult;
            }
        } catch (final IOException ignored) {
        }
    }

    try {
        final Result result = createResultFromInputStream(inputStream);
        lastResult = result;
        return result;
    } catch (final IOException ignored) {
    } catch (final SAXException ignored) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

It finally cracks at the line "new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")));".

```
    /**
 * @param inputStream
 * @return
 * @throws SAXException
 * @throws IOException
 */
private Result createResultFromInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) throws SAXException,
        IOException {
    final Document document = newDocumentBuilder().parse(
            new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")));
    final Element root = document.getDocumentElement(); // lfm element
    final String statusString = root.getAttribute("status");
    final Status status = "ok".equals(statusString) ? Status.OK : Status.FAILED;
    if (status == Status.FAILED) {
        final Element errorElement = (Element)root.getElementsByTagName("error").item(0);
        final int errorCode = Integer.parseInt(errorElement.getAttribute("code"));
        final String message = errorElement.getTextContent();
        return Result.createRestErrorResult(errorCode, message);
    } else {
        return Result.createOkResult(document);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I have no idea what might be wrong. If sufficient info is provided then let me know - I'll get what you need. I'm a beginner. :)

Comment: What line does the NPE happen at?

Comment: Just added the info in the thread @user3580294

Comment: Never ignore an IOException. At least log it.

Comment: Have you done debugging to ensure `inputStream` isn't null? And that the constructor calls don't return `null`?

Comment: @user3580294
I've tried this fix. Will report later if that did fix it.
'      if(inputStream == null) {
          return Result.createRestErrorResult(3, "No internet connection");
      }'

Comment: @olokos Have you tried breaking up the nested constructor? Test if `inputStream` is null, and if it isn't, create a new `InputStreamReader`, and if that isn't null, create a new `InputSource`. If those aren't null, check to see if the result of `newDocumentBuilder()` is null.

Comment: If anyone would ever find this question and may consider it useful - the above code did actually fix the issue. Sorry for so late reply user. I completely forgot after I finally dealt with it.